# Can I use protobuf-net to serialize and deserialize ConcurrentDictionaries to the same file and then read it?

Tags: c#, performance, io, protobuf-net, concurrentdictionary

So I am working on the communication manager for a naval simulator that manages both communications and stores all the data and I need to serialize to file big ConcurrentDictionaries fast and at maximum 10 times per second, the number of times that I need to do this is variable as this is our attempt to implement a replay feature and the number of serializations depends on how long the simulation took. After some research I landed on protobuf-net but I can't figure it out.
The objects I need to work with are quite complex classes with a lot of properties, some of which are custom types and inherit from classes that inherit from other classes. The concurrent dictionaries look something like this `ConcurrentDictionary<string, MyClass>`
The only thing I think I got right is decorating the classes with the attributes. I can't figure out the rest.

I need to serialize a lot of times to the same file and then read that file to recreate the ConcurrentDictionaries. I tried different approaches but without any kind of success...I need a direction.

The problem I think lies in the fact that I serialize multiple times to the same file and when I deserialize I just feed the file as a stream to the `Serializer.Deserialize` method. I think it tries to read the whole file and breaks up...

EDIT: as suggested I added more details reguarding the program.

Comment: Are you intending to overwrite or append the data? What is "big" in this context? Why are you serializing and immediately deserializing? That just seem like a bunch of unnecessary work. You might also want to convert your concurrent dictionary to a regular dictionary, and your objects to data transfer objects to make serialization easier.

Comment: @JonasH I would like to append each serialization of the ConcurrentDictionary and then read it with a "rythm". 
Big to me is like a Concurrent Dictionary of ~100 objects with ~100 properties each. 
I do not need to deserialize it immediately, the point is to implement something like a replay function, where I get the data and the reload it at a later time. 

I was thinking about making something like a surrogate class for ConcurrentDictionary where I use a dictionary and manage the thread safety myself but as a junior developer with a ~10000 lines project it seems a bit daunting and scary.

Comment: How many are the `ConcurrentDictionary<string, MyClass>`? Are you storing them in a list of dictionaries?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Atm I have 11 `ConcurrentDictionary<string, CustomClass>` where each one contains a different type of objects, but it could grow in the future. No I have them hard coded for each type as performance are more important than code complexity to the company.

Comment: Let's say that you want to add a 12th dictionary, and the file contains currently 11 dictionaries. What will be the desirable behavior of your program? Crash with an error message, suggesting to delete the existing file? Load the 11 dictionaries and leave empty the 12th? Something else?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias That is handled by another file containing the version name of the program that is read and compared to the one in the code. The idea is that when you add something you update the version name in the code. If the two names do not match the application tells you and ignores the request to load the replay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bit to unpack here.

To serialize multiple independent objects to the same stream you can use `Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix` / `Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix`. This should allow you to serialize objects one after each other. See [ProtoInclude](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/642677/Protobuf-net-the-unofficial-manual) for how to handle inheritance.

To serialize each object I would tend to prefer to convert the objects into a separate type that is only used for serialization. Sometimes called a Data Transfer Object or DTO. This lets you separate the concerns of serialization from all kinds of domain logic, at the cost of some duplication of code.

There are a few ways to manage size. One approach is to only change *changes* to state, not the entire state. Something similar is sometimes used for games, where you only need to record the user input to allow you to replay the entire game. Another approach is compression, since states probably do not change that much. [LZ4](https://github.com/MiloszKrajewski/K4os.Compression.LZ4) claims to be one of the faster algorithms around. You might also want to keep things in memory if possible, since even the fastest SSD is much slower than memory.

I would highly recommend setting up a simple test environment. I.e. start by serializing a simple object, continue with a complex object, a dictionary of complex objects, and so on. This is also a good opportunity to measure performance.

Comment: I did as you suggested and built a small test environment emulating this part of my program and succeded in decorating the classes with ProtoInclude and (i think) serializing with `Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix`, the problem lies in the deserialization part. When I call the deserialization method I expect to have the first instance of the dictionary deserialized. Somehow I get the last one.

Comment: [Here](https://pastebin.com/7wGJmXgh) I pasted both the serialization and deserialization methods I use

Comment: @MrBott_a If you intend to append multiple objects you need to use `File.Open(path, FileMode.Append)`, If you use `File.Create` you will just overwrite the file. But if you are going to write many objects you might want to keep the stream open.

Answer (score 1):

You could declare a container (struct or class) that contains your dictionaries as members, and then serialize/deserialize this container. Here is an example:

```
[ProtoContract]
struct MyDictionaries
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public ConcurrentDictionary<string, int> A;
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public ConcurrentDictionary<string, char> B;
}

public static void Main()
{
    MyDictionaries dictionaries = new();
    dictionaries.A = new();
    dictionaries.A.TryAdd("A", 1);
    dictionaries.A.TryAdd("B", 2);
    dictionaries.B = new();
    dictionaries.B.TryAdd("C", 'c');
    dictionaries.B.TryAdd("D", 'd');
    Console.WriteLine($"dictionaries.A: {String.Join(", ", dictionaries.A)}");
    Console.WriteLine($"dictionaries.B: {String.Join(", ", dictionaries.B)}");
    MemoryStream stream = new();
    Serializer.Serialize(stream, dictionaries);
    Console.WriteLine();

    stream.Position = 0;
    var deserialized = Serializer.Deserialize<MyDictionaries>(stream);
    Console.WriteLine($"deserialized.A: {String.Join(", ", deserialized.A)}");
    Console.WriteLine($"deserialized.B: {String.Join(", ", deserialized.B)}");
}
```

Output:

```
dictionaries.A: [A, 1], [B, 2]
dictionaries.B: [D, d], [C, c]

deserialized.A: [A, 1], [B, 2]
deserialized.B: [D, d], [C, c]
```

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0mWYlH).

The documentation [states explicitly](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/wiki/Getting-Started#notes-on-types) that `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>` types are supported, and there is also a `ConcurrentDictionarySerializer` in the [source code](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/blob/14da8b12ed5ca62d84aa16066f74349a9ee7c5d8/src/protobuf-net.Core/Serializers/MapSerializer.Concurrent.cs#L20).

Comment: Yes but this serializes only one time on the stream and then deserializes it, I need to do something more along the line of [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uSEG4F).
But the output i get looks like this: 
`dict1: [A, 1], [B, 2]
dictX: [C, 3], [D, 4]
dict1PD: [C, 3], [D, 4], [A, 1], [B, 2]
dictXPD: `

Comment: @MrBott_a ah, you want to store multiple dictionaries in the safe file. Do you know exactly how many dictionaries will be stored in the file, or their number is variable?

Comment: @MrBott_a example using a [`ValueTuple<T1,T2>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple-2): [link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nUnNOs)

Comment: It is variable, I'm working on the communication manager in a naval simulation system and my program manages both communication and keeps all the data about the entire simulation. So the number of times an object is serialized depends on how long the simulation is running...it could be even hours

Comment: MrBott_a I think that this is important information, that should be included in the question.

Comment: updated as per your request, thanks for the suggestion :)